# How to get "read books"

Tags: facebook

I am going to get my friends books that they read them. I've set `user_actions.books`, `friends_actions.books` permissions in my Facebook application but I don't know how I can use related code in my Java program (using facebook4j).
I used:

```
ResponseList<Friend> friends = facebook.getFriends(new Reading().fields("book_reads"));
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Could you be more specific? As in what platform you're working on. Also, have you tried the Graph Explorer?

Comment: Field name is just `books`, not `book_reads`. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cbooks

Comment: I used:ResponseList<Friend> friends = facebook.getFriends(newReading().fields(" books"));
         for (Friend friend : friends) {ResponseList<Book> frbooks=facebook.getBooks(friend.getId());}                              but it returns "books" that my friends like

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint would be for the Access Token user

```
GET /me/books.reads
```

and for the Access Token user's friends

```
GET /me/friends/books.reads
```

So, I guess in Java it would be

```
ResponseList friends = facebook.getFriends(new Reading().fields("books.reads"));
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/books.reads/#read

Comment: thanks alot. I used                                ResponseList<Book> myreadbooks=facebook.getBooks(user.getId(),new Reading().fields("books.reads"));         
            for (Book myreadb :myreadbooks){
                System.out.println(myreadb.getName());
            } but it returns "null"

Comment: That's not correct, Books are referring to User Likes (Books), what you are querying here is OpenGraph actions! Apparantly these are not yet supported by Facebook4J: http://facebook4j.org/en/not-supported.html It seems that this library is quite outdated, RestFB should be a better choice.