# Additional fields (author, isbn) for /{user}/books.reads

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

## Introduction

`/me/books.reads` returns books<sup>[1]</sup>.

It includes an array of books and the following fields for each book:

- title
- type
- id
- url

## Problem

1. I'd like to get the author name(s) at least. I know that `written_by` is an existing field for books.
2. I'd like to get ISBN, if possible.

## Current situation

I tried this:

`/me/books.reads?fields=data.fields(author)`
or
`/me/books.reads?fields=data.fields(book.fields(author))`

But the error response is:

`"Subfields are not supported by data"`

The `books.reads` response looks like this (just one book included):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "00000", 
      "from": {
        "name": "User name", 
        "id": "11111"
      }, 
      "start_time": "2013-07-18T23:50:37+0000", 
      "publish_time": "2013-07-18T23:50:37+0000", 
      "application": {
        "name": "Books", 
        "id": "174275722710475"
      }, 
      "data": {
        "book": {
          "id": "192511337557794", 
          "url": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/A-Semantic-Web-Primer/192511337557794", 
          "type": "books.book", 
          "title": "A Semantic Web Primer"
        }
      }, 
      "type": "books.reads", 
      "no_feed_story": false, 
      "likes": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_like": true, 
        "user_likes": false
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_comment": true, 
        "comment_order": "chronological"
      }
    }
}
```

If I take the id of a book, I can get its metadata from the open graph, for example http://graph.facebook.com/192511337557794 returns something like this:

```
{
   "category": "Book",
   "description": "\u003CP>The development of the Semantic Web...",
   "genre": "Computers",
   "is_community_page": true,
   "is_published": true,
   "talking_about_count": 0,
   "were_here_count": 0,
   "written_by": "Grigoris Antoniou, Paul Groth, Frank Van Harmelen",
   "id": "192511337557794",
   "name": "A Semantic Web Primer",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/A-Semantic-Web-Primer/192511337557794",
   "likes": 1
}
```

The response includes ~10 fields, including `written_by` which has the authors of the book.

Curiously, `link` field seems to map to `url` of the `books.reads` response. However, the field names are different, so I'm starting to loose hope that I would be able to ask for `written_by` in `books.reads` request..

The only reference that I've found about /me/books is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/books.book/

- This is essentially about user sharing that he/she has read a book, not the details of the book itself.
- The data structure is focused on *the occasion of reading a book*: when reading was started, when this story was published, etc.

<sub>[1] I know this thanks to [How to get "read books"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671494/how-to-get-read-books/21671974#21671974)</sub>

Comment: If not possible to do in one graph api style request, any help to do this in some other way would be appreciated: be it FQL or some kind of batch request.

Answer (score 0):

FQl does not looks very promising – although you can request `books` from the `user` table, it seems to deliver just a string value with only the book titles comma-separated.

You can search `page` table by `name` – but I doubt it will work with `name in (subquery)` when what that subquery delivers is just one string of the format `'title 1,title 2,…'`.

Can’t really test this right now, because I have read only one book so far (ahm, one that I have set as “books I read” on FB, not in general …) – but using that to search the page table by name already delivers a multitude of pages, and even if I narrow that selection down by `AND is_community_page=1`, I still get several, so no real way of telling which would be the right one, I guess.

---

So, using the Graph API and a batch request seems to be more promising.

Similar to an FQL multi-query, batch requests also allow you to refer data from the previous “operation” in a batch, by giving operations a “name”, and then referring to data from the first operation by using *JSONPath expression format* (see [Specifying dependencies between operations in the request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/#operations) for details).

So a batch query for this could look like this,

```
[
 {"method":"GET","name":"get-books","relative_url":"me\/books?fields=id"},
 {"method":"GET","relative_url":"?ids={result=get-books:$.data.*.id}
  &fields=description,name,written_by"}
]
```

Here all in one line, for easier copy&paste, so that line breaks don’t cause syntax errors:

```
[{"method":"GET","name":"get-books","relative_url":"me\/books?fields=id"},{"method":"GET","relative_url":"?ids={result=get-books:$.data.*.id}&fields=description,name,written_by"}]
```

So, to test this:

Go to [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).
Change method to POST via the dropdown, and clear whatever is in the field right next to it.
Click “Add a field”, and input name `batch`, and as value insert the line copy&pasted from above.
Since that will also get you a lot of “headers” you might not be interested in, you can add one more field, name `include_headers` and value `false` to get rid of those.

In the result, you will get a field named `body`, that contains the JSON-encoded data for the second query. If you want more fields, add them to the `fields` parameter of the second query, or leave that parameter out completely if you want all of them.

OK, after some trial-and-error I managed to create a [direct link to Graph API Explorer to test this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=POST&path=%3Fbatch%3D%255B%257B%2522method%2522%253A%2522GET%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522get-books%2522%252C%2522relative_url%2522%253A%2522me%255C%252Fbooks%253Ffields%253Did%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522method%2522%253A%2522GET%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522foo%2522%252C%2522relative_url%2522%253A%2522%253Fids%253D%257Bresult%253Dget-books%253A%2524.data.%252A.id%257D%2522%257D%255D%26include_headers%3Dfalse) – the right amount of URL-encoding to use is a little fiddly to figure out :-)
(I left out the `fields` parameter for the second operation here, so this will give you all the info for the book that there is.)

---

As I said, I only got one book on FB, but this should work for a user with multiple books the same way (since the second operation just takes however many IDs it is given from the first one).

But I can’t tell you off the top of my head how this will work for *a lot* of books – how slow the second operation might get with that, when you set a high `limit` for the first one. And I also don’t know how this will behave in regard to *pagination*, which you might run into when `me/books` delivers a lot of books for a user.

But I think this should be a good enough starting point for you to figure the rest out by trying it on users with more data. HTH.

---

Edit: ISBN does not seem to be part of the info for a book’s community page, at least not for the ones I checked. And also `written_by` is optional – my book doesn’t have it. So you’ll only get that info if it is actually provided.